Number of primes in interval is contour integral

(Langmann) Let $a>b \geq 5$ be integers and denote by $\mathcal{C}$ the circle in the complex plane with center $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and radius $\frac{a-b+1}{2}$. Then
$$
\pi(a)-\pi(b-1)=-\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{z \sin \left(\pi \frac{\Gamma(z)}{z}\right)}{\sin (\pi z)} d z\right\rfloor,
$$
where $\Gamma(z)$ is the Gamma function and $\pi(z)$ the prime counting function.

The proof by the guy who found this goes like this:
If $n \geq 5$ is not a prime number, then the residue $\operatorname{Res}_n$ of the integrand at the point $z=n$ is equal to $0$, since $(n-1)!$ is then divisible by $n$. For prime numbers $n$, the residual $\operatorname{Res}_n$ is equal to $-(n / \pi) \sin (\pi / n)$ due to Wilson's theorem, from which the assertion follows easily.

I do not understand anything happening here. I only found the residue theorem, which I knew but I had to fresh my knowledge up a bit:

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an elementary domain, i.e. a simply connected domain in the complex number plane. Furthermore, let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined except for an exceptional set $D_f$ of isolated singularities in $D$, $I$ a real interval and $J: I \rightarrow D \backslash D_f$ a closed path in $D \backslash D_f$. Then the following applies to the complex path integral
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi \mathrm{i}} \int_{\gamma} f=\sum_{a \in D_f} \operatorname{ind}_{J}(a) \operatorname{Res}_a f
$$
where $\operatorname{ind}_{J}(a)$ is the orbital number of $J$ with respect to $a$ and $\operatorname{Res}_a f$ is the residual of $f$ in $a$.

Can someone help me a bit with some more explanation on what is going on here?
Source: Langmann, K. Eine Formel für die Anzahl der Primzahlen. Arch. Math 25, 40 (1974). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01238637

Doesn't this count primes only approximately? With bounded error though?

@MartinR The Gamma function, somehow the big G got small.

This isn't a complete answer but is too long for a comment and perhaps provides some insight.

The residues of the integrand
$$f(z)=\frac{z \sin\left(\pi \frac{\Gamma(z)}{z}\right)}{\sin(\pi z)}=z \csc(\pi z) \sin\left(\pi \frac{\Gamma(z)}{z}\right)$$
can be calculated at positive integer values of $z$ but at non-positive integer values of $z$ the poles of $\Gamma(z)$ are problematic.

Here are the first few residues of $f(z)$ at positive integer values of $z$.
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 z & \text{res}(f(s),\{s,z\}) \\
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & \frac{2}{\pi } \\
 3 & -\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2 \pi } \\
 4 & -\frac{4}{\pi } \\
 5 & -\frac{5 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}}{2 \pi } \\
 6 & 0 \\
 7 & -\frac{7 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)}{\pi } \\
 8 & 0 \\
 9 & 0 \\
 10 & 0 \\
 11 & -\frac{11 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)}{\pi } \\
 12 & 0 \\
 13 & -\frac{13 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{13}\right)}{\pi } \\
 14 & 0 \\
 15 & 0 \\
 16 & 0 \\
 17 & -\frac{17 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{17}\right)}{\pi } \\
 18 & 0 \\
 19 & -\frac{19 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{19}\right)}{\pi } \\
 20 & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

The following table illustrates the residue calculated by Mathematica is inconsistent with the formula in the question above at $z=2$, so it appears the question in the formula is only valid at primes for $z>2$. Also note the non-zero residue at $z=4$ in the table above.
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
 z & \text{res}(f(s),\{s,z\}) & -\frac{z}{\pi} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right) \\
 2 & \frac{2}{\pi } & -\frac{2}{\pi } \\
 3 & -\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2 \pi } & -\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2 \pi } \\
 5 & -\frac{5 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}}{2 \pi } & -\frac{5 \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}}{\pi } \\
 7 & -\frac{7 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)}{\pi } & -\frac{7 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)}{\pi } \\
 11 & -\frac{11 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)}{\pi } & -\frac{11 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)}{\pi } \\
 13 & -\frac{13 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{13}\right)}{\pi } & -\frac{13 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{13}\right)}{\pi } \\
 17 & -\frac{17 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{17}\right)}{\pi } & -\frac{17 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{17}\right)}{\pi } \\
 19 & -\frac{19 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{19}\right)}{\pi } & -\frac{19 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{19}\right)}{\pi } \\
\end{array}$$

The contour defined in the question seems to suggest $\pi(a)-\pi(b-1)$ can be evaluated as
$$\pi(a)-\pi(b-1)=-\left\lfloor\sum\limits_{n=\left\lceil\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{1}{2} (a-b+1)\right\rceil}^{\frac{1}{2} (a-b+1)+\frac{a+b}{2}} \text{res}(f(z),\{z,n\})\right\rfloor=-\left\lfloor\sum\limits_{n=\left\lceil b-\frac{1}{2}\right\rceil }^{a+\frac{1}{2}} \text{res}(f(z),\{z,n\})\right\rfloor$$
which I validated is correct for integer values of $a$ in the range $6\le a \le 100$ and integer values of $b$ in the range $5\le b \le a+1$.
